# Как добавить в Wordpress виджет вывод дефолтной картинки миниатюры

Tags: wordpress, виджет, themes

У меня есть виджет с таким кодом:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'category' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
); 
$recent_post = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
foreach( $recent_post as $recent ){
 if($recent['post_status']=="publish"){
    if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"])) {
        echo '<li class="shortcode-recent_articles">
        <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Посмотреть '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'res_article_image'). $recent["post_title"].'</a>'.'<br>'.
                $excerpt = wp_trim_words( $recent['post_content'], 30); 
        '</li>';
    }else{
        echo '<li style="padding:3px;border-bottom:1px solid green;">
        <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Посмотреть '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a>'.'<br>'.
                $excerpt = wp_trim_words( $recent['post_content'], 30); 
        '</li>';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Также у меня в синглах:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <figure class="some class">
        <?php
        the_post_thumbnail('full_thumb');
        } else { ?>
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default-image.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
```

Как мне добавить вывод этой картинки в виджет, если у поста нет заданной миниатюры?

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте код виджета таким образом:

```
$args        = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'category'    => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$recent_post = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach ( $recent_post as $recent ) {
    if ( $recent['post_status'] == "publish" ) {
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"] ) ) {
            echo '<li class="shortcode-recent_articles">' .
                 '<a href="' . get_permalink( $recent["ID"] ) . '" title="Посмотреть ' .
                 esc_attr( $recent["post_title"] ) . '" >' .
                 get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"], 'res_article_image' ) .
                 $recent["post_title"] . '</a>' .
                 '<br>' . wp_trim_words( $recent['post_content'], 30 ) . '</li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li style="padding:3px; border-bottom:1px solid green;">' .
                 '<a href="' . get_permalink( $recent["ID"] ) . '" title="Посмотреть ' .
                 esc_attr( $recent["post_title"] ) . '" >' .
                 '<img src="' . bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/img/default-image.jpg" alt="' . the_title(). '"/>' .
                 $recent["post_title"] . '</a>' .
                 '<br>' . wp_trim_words( $recent['post_content'], 30 ) . '</li>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Выдает http://mysite/wp-content/themes/mythemeГлавная в папку img не заходит видимо

Comment: выводит линк /img/default-image.jp, вместо http://mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/default-image.jpg .

Comment: а начало линка перед <li>

Comment: Судя по сумбурности и противоречивости ваших комментариев, вы не смогли скопировать мой код к себе на сайт. "Выводит jp вместо jpg" - это нечто. При том, что в моем коде написано jpg. <a> в моем коде тоже внутри <li>

Comment: по поводу "jp" это моя опечатка в комментарии, приношу свои извинения.  На страницу мне выводит http://mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme<li class="shortcode-recent_articles"><a href="http://mysite/news/po-itogam-pervogo-kvartala/" title="Посмотреть По итогам первого квартала"><img src="/img/default-image.jpg" alt=" ">По итогам первого квартала</a><br>По итогам первого квартала …</li> И при полном копипасте кода, тоже.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответы. Разобрался вместо . bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) надо get_template_directory_uri(). По крайней мере так заработало. Поправьте меня если это не правильно.

Comment: Я не вдавался во второй кусок кода с bloginfo, вы же написали, что он у вас работает в single